# Gradient estimate of parabolic Cauchy problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde, cauchy-problem

Consider the Cauchy problem
$$\left\{\hspace{5pt}\begin{aligned}
&-\dfrac{\partial u }{\partial t} 
+a\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
+b \dfrac{\partial u }{\partial x} 
+c u
= f(u) \leq 0& \hspace {10pt} &\text{for $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}  \times (0,T]$}
;\\
&u(x,T) = e^x\geq 0 & \hspace{10pt} &\text{for $x \in  \mathbb{R}$.}
\end{aligned}\right.$$
Here we assume that $u$, $a>0$, $b$, $c<0$, $f \leq 0$ and $g\geq 0$ are smooth enough. Moreover, I know that the solution $u$ grows slower than the fundamental solution.

I am going to ask if the gradient $\partial_x u$ also grows slower than the fundamental solution. Due to the nonlinear $f(u)$, we can not differentiate the Green representation of $u$ to estimate the gradient bound.

Comment: What do you mean by the fundamental solution in this case?

Comment: What is g? What are conditions on f, say, is it bounded? Also as written it's a heat equation with reverse time. Is it proven that such a solution exists?

Comment: @Andrew time is not reversed. There is a negative sign in front of the time derivative and $a>0$, so the equation is uniformly parabolic.

Comment: The initial data is on the upper boundary so effectively it's  a reversed time problem. And what about other questions?